# Path of web applications

Tags: jsp, web-applications, tomcat, servlets

I am using a web application deployed in Apache Tomcat webserver where I am facing an issue basically getting HTTP Status 404 No Such File or Directory. I can understand the following message as follows - 
 HTTP Status 404  - /s2j-main.jsp

In this scenario the web container searches for the file (s2j-main.jsp) in the top web deployment folder. For example if the web container root is a folder s2j, it will search in webapps/s2j folder for Tomcat. However, if the error comes as

HTTP Status 404 - s2j-main.jsp (minus the slash /)  In which path exactly is the webcontainer expecting the resource (s2j-main.jsp) to be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tomcat has a ROOT webapp under `/webapps/ROOT`
Assume you have a jsp s2j-main.jsp placed at `/webapps/ROOT/s2j-main.jsp`, then this will be accessible as

`http://<url:port>/s2j-main.jsp`

If you have your own webapp named s2j and it is placed at `/webapps/s2j`, then any JSP under this will by default be accessible at

`http://<url:port>/s2j/s2j-main.jsp`

Note - the name of the webapp becomes part of the URL unless you have defined a `Context` in `server.xml` with a path as "/"

Only then does s2j become the root web application.

Now as you are seeing 404s on /s2j-main.jsp, it is because of either of the above, you're not placed it in the actual ROOT or you are trying the incorrect URL